# Get running build status on a given Jenkins worker node

Tags: jenkins, autoscaling, jenkins-cli

I'm trying to setup some automation for gracefully removing a worker node in Jenkins. Currently I can do the following to get a node to stop accepting new jobs:

```
  JENKINS_CRUMB=$(curl -v -c /tmp/cookie -u "$user:$pass" "$JENKINS_URL/crumbIssuer/api/json" | jq -r '.crumb')
  echo "CSFR Token: $JENKINS_CRUMB"
  echo "Disabling Node $NODE_NAME"
  curl -v -b /tmp/cookie -u "$user:$pass" "$JENKINS_URL/computer/$NODE_NAME/toggleOffline"

  echo "Waiting for Jobs to Finish"
  ???
```

But after that, I want to wait until any existing jobs that are running are finished before the script exits. I looked through the `/api/computer/` endpoint and it seems to only list the node names, but does not indicate the number of running jobs. I tried `/computer/<worker name>/api/json` and `xml` and they show a bunch of executor attributes, but they don't seem to be populated with metadata on running jobs. They're always empty.

This is running on AWS and I eventually want to call this from SSM Agent (via a Lifecycle hook), triggered whenever an auto-scaling group policy wants to scale down a node. My goal is a clean shutdown, waiting for jobs to finish up so I don't kill a node while a developer has a job running.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a way to do everything through the Jenkins API, but if you use a username and password, and get the CSFR token, you can issue commands to `toggleOffline` which will set a node so that new jobs won't run but existing jobs will finish. Then you can query `/computer/<NODE_NAME>/api/json` (which is an API call, so you don't need the CSFR token) and check for the `idle` parameter. Once the node is idle, you can call `doDelete`

The following snippet assumes the node name is stored in `/node_name` and that `$JENKINS_URL` is set to `http://yourjenkinshostname`. `$cookie` is just a file location so you can set it to `/tmp/something`, and of course you need to define a username and password.

```
  echo "Getting Jenkins CSFR Token"

  JENKINS_CRUMB=$(curl -c $cookie -u "$user:$pass" "$JENKINS_URL/crumbIssuer/api/json" | jq -r '.crumb')
  echo "CSFR Token: $JENKINS_CRUMB"

NODE_NAME=$(cat /node_name)

echo "Disabling Node $NODE_NAME"
curl -H "Jenkins-Crumb:$JENKINS_CRUMB" -X POST \
     -b $cookie -u "$user:$pass" "$JENKINS_URL/computer/$NODE_NAME/toggleOffline"

echo "Waiting for Jobs to Finish"

while true; do
  idle=$(curl -b $cookie -u "$user:$pass" "$JENKINS_URL/computer/$NODE_NAME/api/json" | jq ".idle")
  echo "Node Idle State: $idle"
  if [ "$idle" == "true" ]; then
    echo "Node is idle. Removing Node"
    curl -H "Jenkins-Crumb:$JENKINS_CRUMB" -X POST \
         -b $cookie -u "$user:$pass" "$JENKINS_URL/computer/$NODE_NAME/doDelete"
    exit 0
  else
    echo "Node is Still Busy. Waiting 30s..."
    sleep 30
  fi
done
```